# compare two columns row by row and nan duplicate values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
a  b  c
0  3  0
1  1  4
2  3  3
4  4  1
```

I want to compare a and b to c. If a value in the same row is equal to c I want 'nan' in a and/or b.
Like that:

```
a    b    c
nan  3    0
1    1    4
2    nan  3
4    4    1
```

Comment: Try `out = df.assign(**df[['a','b']].mask(df[['a','b']].eq(df['c'],axis=0)))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `to_numpy` with `DataFrame.mask` for this:

```
eqs = df.loc[:, :'b'].eq(df['c'].to_numpy()[:, None])
df.loc[:, :'b'] = df.loc[:, :'b'].mask(eqs)

     a    b  c
0  NaN  3.0  0
1  1.0  1.0  4
2  2.0  NaN  3
3  4.0  4.0  1
```

Comment: Thank you. In addition: is there a possibility to keep this functionality and if all three vaues are the same, only NaN b or a (doesnt matter which one)